# How to construct a matrix within a matrix

Tags: matrices

How can one construct the following matrix, where each block is a  $3\times 3$ matrix by itself?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Nest `array` in `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  1 & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & 1
  \end{array}
\\ \hline
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & 1 & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  1 & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
\\ \hline
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  1 & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
  &
  \begin{array}{*{3}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
  \end{array}
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

The main trick is to use zero space between columns and fixed width cells.

[image]

Just for fun, a better way to specify those blocks with a single 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\dotblock}{mmm}
 {% #1 is the size, #2 the row for the 1, #3 the column for the 1
  \userci_dotblock:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_userci_dotblock_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \userci_dotblock:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_userci_dotblock_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
   {%
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
     {% ##1 = row index, ####1 = column index
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_userci_dotblock_body_tl
       {
        \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
         { \int_compare_p:n { ##1=#2 } }
         { \int_compare_p:n { ####1=#3 } }
         { 1 }
         { \cdot }
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 = #1 } { & } 
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_userci_dotblock_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{array}{*{#1}{w{c}{1em}}}
  \tl_use:N \l_userci_dotblock_body_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \dotblock{3}{1}{1}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{2}{2}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{3}{3}
\\ \hline
  \dotblock{3}{3}{2}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{1}{3}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{2}{1}
\\ \hline
  \dotblock{3}{2}{3}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{3}{1}
  &
  \dotblock{3}{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can nest an array within a `pmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}
        1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
        \hline
       \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \hline
       \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot& \cdot & \cdot
      \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `{array}` and add parenthesis with `\left`-`\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\left(
\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc|ccc@{}}
1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     \\ 
\hline
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\hline
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1     & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\end{array}
\right)$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]